# return array jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have problem to return array in jquery. I used ajax to response data from mysql and I have to add it do array and return.

This is my code:

```
function addOption()
    {
         itemsarray = [];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data:{
                option: 'com_zamowienia',
                view: 'zamowienia_lista',
                task: 'getStatusy'
            },
            success: function(data){
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);         
                    for (x=0; x<obj.length; x++) {
                        itemsarray.push(obj[x].nazwa);
                }
            }
        });

        return itemsarray;
    }
```

When I use : alert(addOption()). I see empty alert

Comment: By default, AJAX calls are asynchronous.  You can not return the results from the function, as it has not happened at the time it finishes.

Answer (score 4):

As ***AJAX*** is asynchronous, so you can't return array like that.

So, you should use callback function to get the array:

```
function addOption(callback)
    {
         itemsarray = [];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data:{
                option: 'com_zamowienia',
                view: 'zamowienia_lista',
                task: 'getStatusy'
            },
            success: function(data){
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);         
                for (x=0; x<obj.length; x++) {
                        itemsarray.push(obj[x].nazwa);
                }
                // return you itemsarray through callback function parameter
                callback(itemsarray);
            }
        });
    }
```

Call the function like:

```
addOption(function(myarr) {
   console.log( myarr );
});
```